# verb "arguments" to open graph actions

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to define facebook graph actions for my application.

Users can give their opinion about animals, an animal can be either *good* or *bad*. I want to publish their votes using timeline and the Open Graph API:

> John thinks elephants are good.

or

> John thinks snakes are bad.

It it possible to achieve this? can I have a *think* verb with good/bad as arguments? or can I have two verbs: "to think *object* is good", "to think *object* is bad" and somehow configure the app to display the text as I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom properties to actions, see [1] and [2].

While you can easily access these properties when building aggregations, I'm not sure if you can get them to display in the simple action message published … (Maybe via translation settings of your app? But I doubt it.)

Maybe you could use the message parameter, and pre-fill it with "I think elephants are good/bad" when publishing the action? (Then you might have to change your action verb to something like "rating" an animal or else for it to make sense.)

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-actions/#custom
[2] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#instance-property

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible, as you have three variables in your action. The `object` would be the animal and the `action` would be 'thinks' but there is no room to add the 'good' and 'bad'. Facebook will only let you do something in the form `User is {action} {object}`, not `User is {action} {object} is {good|bad}`.